# integrating applications with Sage People (HRIS/ HRMS)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have been asked to develope integrations solution for Sage People application which is a HRMS tool build on Salesforce platform. Integration capabilities of Sage People are poorly documentation and limited to file based integrations only . Sage people objects are showed as managed objects in Salesforce. I just want to confirm the possiibility of  whether I will be able to use Salesforce Apex functionality to receive Data from external API and change records in Sage People.

Answer (score 0):

Even in the manage packages, it is possible to change the records. Apart from that, it is also possible to change the fields on the manage package objects. To use in the API you may write custom API or use the standard API